# upgrading struts 2 jar

Tags: struts2

In a Struts 2 based project, one of the jar files i am using is struts2-core-2.0.14.jar, and when i removed this jar and replaced this with struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar the application fails to start.

Comment: Be more informative...whats the error??

Comment: Are you using anything to manage dependencies? i.e., Maven

Answer (score 0):

Most Probable, as far as i understand, the problem is with the filter class declared in web.xml

For the version of struts2.0.x,The class "org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher" is used as filter.

For the version of struts2.1.x,The class "org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter" is used as filter.

For more inform, please refer 
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/difference-between-struts-2-filterdispatcher-and-strutsprepareandexecutefilter/